# Where should .gitignore file be located in IntelliJ?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gitignore

When initializing Git in IntelliJ, a .gitignore file is created in the .idea folder. However, many of the suggestions I have seen about the .gitignore file say to ignore the .idea folder. Wouldn't this ignore the .gitignore file itself, or not be possible? Where should the .gitignore file be located?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Where should the .gitignore file be located?

`.gitignore` is a file used by `git` to specify which files should be ignored when making commits. It has nothing to do with IntelliJ. You can have as many or as few of these files as you wish. For more details about this file, [see the official documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

The `.gitignore` file that IntelliJ IDEA generates under the `.idea` folder is specific to that folder and its subfolders. Git allows this so you can specify what to ignore under a specific folder and JetBrains leverages that feature.

> However, many of the suggestions I have seen about the .gitignore file say to ignore the .idea folder.

In many projects, it is common practice to ignore files for a specific IDE or environment. This is especially true in projects that are developed by a team where each member of the team uses a different editor.

On the other hand, if everyone on the team uses the same editor, then it can be helpful to include some of these files in the git repository. This allows the team to share configuration.

If you are the only person on the project, then it makes even more sense to commit files in the `.idea` folder. Then when you get a new computer, you can clone your repo to the new machine and have most of the editor configuration ready to go.

In the end, whether or not you commit the `.idea` folder is entirely up to you. You may want to read [JetBrains suggestions](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839) to make an informed decision.

Comment: So the .gitignore file in the .idea folder can't ignore the whole .idea folder, because it's inside it (but it can ignore some elements of that folder)? Should the .gitignore file then be committed?

Comment: @RonanVenkat Correct, a `.gitignore` file cannot ignore the folder which contains it. It can only ignore files and subfolders of that folder. If you want to add `.idea` to the `.gitignore` in the root of the project, then you don't need to commit `.idea/.gitignore`. On the other hand, if you want to commit any files in the `.idea` folder, then you should commit `.idea/.gitignore` since it contains rules to ignore files that may contain sensitive data such as keys or passwords as well as files that are specific to your file system and may contain absolute paths or local settings.

Comment: Couldn't that all be achieved with just a .gitignore file in the root of the project?

Comment: @RonanVenkat Yes, it can. Consider the situation where your root `.gitignore` file is very large. Moving pieces to individual subfolders can help make it more manageable.